Number of ways to buy an ice cream
Here is the problem: "In an ice cream shop there are seven flavors of ice cream, including chocolate. A person wants to buy a four-scoop ice cream".
Since $n=7,k=4$, then the number of ways to buy the ice cream is
$$\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{7+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{10}{3}=120$$
If two scoops, at least, must be chocolate, it remains $k=4-2=2$ flavors to choose, hence there are
$$\binom{7+2-1}{2-1}=\binom{8}{1}=8$$
ways to buy four-scoop ice cream with at least 2 chocolate scoops.
At last, in the  case the flavours must be different, we have
$$\binom{7}{4}=35$$
ways to buy it.

Strange problem statement .. it's just stating some facts, not a question.   I suppose the question is how many different 4-scoop ice creams there can be?  Does the order matter?  E.g. are they stacked on a cone, and since some people first want to eat some vanilla before chocolate, does order matter? Or if they are in a dish, would they be in a square, or 3 at bottom and 1 on top?  Could you have 2 scoops of vanilla and 2 scoops of frozen roadkill?  Details, details, please!

@Bram28 yes, this is the problem.

"In an ice cream shop there are seven flavors of ice cream, including chocolate. A person wants to by a four-scoop ice cream".  The answer to what is being asked is "If the person has money, let him".  That's the answer.  If you wanted another answer, you should actually ask a question.

$7^4$ would be the ways he can choose what flavor the first scoop is, what flavor the second scoop is, what flavor the third is and what flavor the fourth is.

The number of $k$-scoop choices out of $n$ distinct flavors where there is no restriction on repeated flavors, should be $$\binom{n+k-1}{k}. \tag{1}$$  You can test it for yourself when $k = 1$:  in such a case, there are obviously $n$ possible choices for the single scoop, which matches $(1)$ but your formula would give you $\binom{n+1-1}{1-1} = \binom{n}{0} = 1$.  So the correct answer is $$\binom{7+4-1}{4} = \binom{10}{4} = 210.$$
Your reasoning for the second part of the question is correct, but your calculation is incorrect for the same reason as the first part.
Your answer to the third part of the question is correct.

In the second part should be $\binom{8}{2}$ instead?

@mvfs314 Correct.  There are $28$ such choices for which at least two of the four scoops are chocolate.  You can even write them out explicitly; e.g., if "chocolate" is denoted by $1$ and the other flavors are numbered $2$ through $7$, then you can write out $(1,1,1,1), (1,1,1,2), \ldots, (1,1,1,7)$ and that's already $7$ different ways.  Then you have $(1,1,2,2), (1,1,2,3), \ldots, (1,1,2,7)$ for another $6$ ways, plus $(1,1,3,3), \ldots, (1,1,3,7)$, etc.  So you can see it should be $7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 28$ ways.
